Too much arguments shown when used LOOKUP
I'm using formula LOOKUP in EXCEL 2013 as shown below:
=LOOKUP(1,0/(($B3=Master!$A:$A)*(F$2=Master!$B:$B)),Master!$C:$C,"")
But now it's jump out said I entered too many arguments for this function, is there a solution?

1,0 contains also a separator: ,.
Replace the it with a . or just remove it:
=LOOKUP(1/(($B3=Master!$A:$A)*(F$2=Master!$B:$B)),Master!$C:$C,"")

Thanks, will try

Do you want to find the last value that meets the conditions?
In my opinion, your formula needs to follow the
syntax: =LOOKUP(1,0/(condition),(query area)), please try: =LOOKUP(1,0/(($B3=Master!$A:$A)*(F$2=Master!$B:$B)),Master!$C:$C)

Reminder: answer section is for concrete answer, if you want the user to try something, use comments
